# db.get is not a fucntion err discord bot

Tags: javascript

I got err at ./events/ready.js:22:28

Err is "db.get is not a fucntion."

I import quick.db but it still have this err and it make my discord bot commands doesn't work

This is my code at ready.js

```
const { ActivityType } = require('discord.js');
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const db = require('quick.db');
const { prefix, prefixalt } = require('../config.json');
const { joinVoiceChannel } = require('@discordjs/voice');
const player = require("../client/player");


module.exports = {
  name: 'ready',
  once: true,
  execute(client) {
    console.log((`Logged in as ${client.user.tag}`).red);
    console.log((`Servers: ${client.guilds.cache.size}`).magenta, (`Users: ${client.guilds.cache
      .reduce((a, b) => a + b.memberCount, 0)
      .toLocaleString()}`).yellow, (`Commands: ${client.commands.size}`).green);
    client.user.setStatus("online")
    client.user.setActivity(`มีใครอยากเลี้ยงแมวดื้อตัวนี้มั้ยยย`, { type: ActivityType.play })
    
    setInterval(async () => {
      client.guilds.cache.forEach(async g => {
        let vch = await db.get(`24_7_${g.id}`)
        if (vch == null) return
        let [gu, ch, tr] = vch
        if (tr == true) {
          let GU = client.guilds.cache.get(gu);
          let CH = client.channels.cache.get(ch);
        const queue = player.createQueue(GU, {
            leaveOnEnd: false,
                leaveOnStop: false,
            channelEmpty: false,
            spotifyBridge: true,
            initialVolume: 75
          });
    if (!queue.connection) queue.connect(CH).catch(() => {
    if (CH == null) return db.delete(`24_7_${g.id}`)
          })
        }
      })
    }, 1000)
  }
};
```

This is my index.js:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();


app.get('/', function (request, response) {
  response.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

app.use('/ping', (req, res) => {
  res.send(new Date());
});

app.listen(8080, () => {
  console.log(('Express is ready.'))
});

const { Client, Collection, Partials, GatewayIntentBits, ActionRowBuilder, ButtonBuilder, ButtonStyle, Events, EmbedBuilder } = require('discord.js');

const config = require("./config.json");
const { glob } = require("glob");
const { promisify } = require("util");
const { joinVoiceChannel } = require('@discordjs/voice');
const { REST } = require('@discordjs/rest');
const { Routes } = require('discord-api-types/v9');
const { SlashCommandBuilder } = require('@discordjs/builders');
const db = require('quick.db');
const colors = require("colors");

const client = new Client({
  intents: [
    GatewayIntentBits.Guilds,
    GatewayIntentBits.GuildMembers,
    GatewayIntentBits.GuildEmojisAndStickers,
    GatewayIntentBits.GuildIntegrations,
    GatewayIntentBits.GuildWebhooks,
    GatewayIntentBits.GuildInvites,
    GatewayIntentBits.GuildVoiceStates,
    GatewayIntentBits.GuildPresences,
    GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessages,
    GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessageReactions,
    GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessageTyping,
    GatewayIntentBits.DirectMessages,
    GatewayIntentBits.DirectMessageReactions,
    GatewayIntentBits.DirectMessageTyping,
    GatewayIntentBits.MessageContent
  ],
  partials: [
    Partials.Message,
    Partials.Channel,
    Partials.GuildMember,
    Partials.Reaction,
    Partials.GuildScheduledEvent,
    Partials.User,
    Partials.ThreadMember
  ],
  shards: "auto",
  allowedMentions: {
    parse: [],
    repliedUser: false
  },
});

//nodejs-events
process.on("unhandledRejection", e => {
  console.log(e)
})
process.on("uncaughtException", e => {
  console.log(e)
})
process.on("uncaughtExceptionMonitor", e => {
  console.log(e)
})

module.exports = client;
client.commands = new Collection();
client.events = new Collection();
client.slashCommands = new Collection();
['commands', 'events', 'slash'].forEach(handler => {
  require(`./handlers/${handler}`)(client);
})

const commands = client.slashCommands.map(({ execute, ...data }) => data);

// Register slash commands
const rest = new REST({ version: '10' }).setToken(config.token || process.env.token);
rest.put(
  Routes.applicationCommands(config.clientID),
  { body: commands },
).then(() => console.log('Successfully registered application commands.'))
        .catch(console.error)

/*
// Register slash commands
const rest = new REST({ version: '10' }).setToken(config.token || process.env.token);
rest.put(
  Routes.applicationGuildCommands(config.clientID, config.guildID),
  { body: commands },
).then(() => console.log('Successfully registered application commands.'))
  .catch(console.error)
*/

setTimeout(() => {
  if (!client || !client.user) {
    console.log("Client Not Login, Process Kill")
    process.kill(1);
  } else {
    console.log("Client Login")
  }
}, 3 * 1000 * 60);

setTimeout(() => {
  process.kill(1);
  console.log("Client Login")
}, 22 * 10000 * 60);

client.login(config.token || process.env.token).catch((err) => {
  console.log(err.message)
})
```

I try to change it but it still have this err

I re install quick.db but it still have it bruh

Comment: Don't copy and paste entire files of code in here. That is not what StackOverflow is meant for. Remember: the more effort it takes on our part, the less likely you are to get a quality answer (or an answer at all)

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple issues with this code.

#1: To use quick.db, you need to create an instance of the `QuickDB` class before calling its methods like `db.set()`.

```js
const { QuickDB } = require("quick.db");
const db = new QuickDB();
```

#2: You are importing quick.db twice. You should pass the first instance created in your `index.js` file to your `ready.js` file. To follow your pattern, you can add it to the client.

```js
client.db = db;
```

By initializing an instance of the `QuickDB` class and passing it to the client, you can use it in `ready.js` and all other handlers.